# How to build a calendar view using data from ics file?

Tags: java, user-interface, icalendar

I am creating a PC program which is based on iCalendar format. I need to be able to get the data from a current ics file and display it as a calendar or at least something similar to calendar. I know how to get the data from ics file just don't have any idea how to easily use that data for displaying purposes.

Here is my starting code:

```
public void getCalendarData(File f) throws FileNotFoundException, IOException, ParserException
{
    FileInputStream fin = new FileInputStream(f);
    builder = new CalendarBuilder();
    calendar = builder.build(fin);
}
```

Comment: you could try this http://ical4j.sourceforge.net/introduction.html

Comment: I am already using that code, but the question is how to display Calendar object, which you get from ics file, in some calendar style view?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One thing is ical4j, which is basically a utility that wraps the ICS format.

Another thing is a front end for a calendar/schedule :-)

But, lucky us, there's a nice JSF component with Primefaces, that you can use if a web interface is OK for you.

http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/data/schedule.xhtml

Basically, what you need, is to just parse the data from ICS and feed the primefaces component data model (the link above has both the JSF and the managed bean example of how to use the component)

So you'd have to so something like this

```
private static final SimpleDateFormat SDF = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd");

@PostConstruct
private void loadIcs() {
    eventModel = new DefaultScheduleModel();
    CalendarBuilder builder = new CalendarBuilder();

    try {
        net.fortuna.ical4j.model.Calendar calendar = builder.build(this.getClass().getResourceAsStream("canada.ics"));

        for (Iterator i = calendar.getComponents().iterator(); i.hasNext();) {
            Component component = (Component) i.next();
            //new event
            Date start = SDF.parse(component.getProperty("DTSTART").getValue());
            Date end = SDF.parse(component.getProperty("DTEND").getValue());
            String summary = component.getProperty("SUMMARY").getValue();

            eventModel.addEvent(new DefaultScheduleEvent(summary,
            start, end));

            System.out.println("added "+start+end+summary);

        }
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (ParserException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (ParseException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}
```

Comment: My application will not be using internet or web based interface. I just want to be able to create some jFrame, put a jTable(or something like that) and be able to show all the information from ics file in that table so it looks like a calendar. It's probably not that simple because I can't find any solutions.

Comment: well, if you find any java desktop GUI component for a schedule, it probably will have some method to add events, and since you can extract these events using the ical4j, all you have to do is to find some schedule graphical component that fits your needs. For example https://code.google.com/p/resource-schedule/

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if you mean the actual GUI or getting the list of dates from an icalendar which is fairly complex given the RRULE properties. In ther first case, the choice is wide open (HTML, ...) in the later case there is an example [here](http://wiki.modularity.net.au/ical4j/index.php?title=Examples#Generating_event_dates) copied below :

```
// Reading the file and creating the calendar
CalendarBuilder builder = new CalendarBuilder();
Calendar cal = null;
try {
    cal = builder.build(new FileInputStream("my.ics"));
} catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
} catch (ParserException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}


// Create the date range which is desired.
DateTime from = new DateTime("20100101T070000Z");
DateTime to = new DateTime("20100201T070000Z");;
Period period = new Period(from, to);


// For each VEVENT in the ICS
for (Object o : cal.getComponents("VEVENT")) {
    Component c = (Component)o;
    PeriodList list = c.calculateRecurrenceSet(period);

    for (Object po : list) {
        System.out.println((Period)po);
    }
}
```

Comment: I think this method will be useful in some cases, but I was aiming to find out how to create GUI with all the dates from ics displayed as a calendar. For example I add some event to my.ics file and I want to see where that event is located in this month, same as looking at a normal calendar.